# How to update price when quantity changes in a shopping cart using jquery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Hi I am developing a shopping cart using jquery.So far I have listed the products and their details. Here is my code

```
foreach( $_SESSION['r'] as $key=>$ar):

$cnt++;
 ?>   <tr>

        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Name']?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $ar['Price']?></td>
       <td align="center">
       <select class="myclass" name="qty" id='qty<?php echo $cnt;?>'>
       <?php for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
               $y="";
               if( $i==$_SESSION['r'][$key]['Quantity']){
                $y="selected";
                }
                echo "<option ";
                echo "value=\"$i\" ".$y.">", $i, "</option>\n";


            } ?>

       </select>
       </td>

        <?php $x=$x+$ar['Quantity']; ?>

         <td name="price" id="price"><span class="priceDisplay<?php echo $cnt;?>"><?php echo $ar['Total']; ?></span></td>
    <!--   <td id="tot" align="center"><?php// echo $ar['Total'] ?></td> -->
        <input type='hidden' name='id' id="pid" value='<?php echo $ar['Id']; ?>'>
        <input type='hidden' name='price' id="price" value='<?php echo $ar['Price'] ?>' class="input">  
       <td><input type='checkbox' name='remove' value='Remove' onCheck="$(this).closest('tr').remove();">
```

Here, my id for drop down list in each row is different.It is generated automatically as the loop continues. All I need is that, when the user changes  a product's quantity corresponding price has to be changed. The thing is that, when the user changes the quantity, jquery has to be invoked.It should pass the select id. But my select id is different for each product. So how I achieve it? Please help me.

Comment: write a javascript onchange of the qty/

Comment: But I am using jquery. So how can I write javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing a function onChange() on the select that calculates the total price?, you could add a class to the container of the price and to the quantity, just to differentiate, then loop through them.

Comment: HI.thank you for your reply.I have not implemented onchange(). Actually can I ask you a doubt?

Comment: Shall we use onchange() in php while we use jquery?

Comment: And how will I get the id in jquery function>Can you please explain>

Comment: @user2934937 - just to get a good answer, re-organize your thoughts and ask a direct question. this will help people here to help you in their part.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td align="center" id="price"><?php echo $ar['Price']?></td>
       <td align="center">

<select class="myclass" name="qty" id='qty<?php echo $cnt;?>' onchange="get_price(this)">
       <?php for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
               $y="";
               if( $i==$_SESSION['r'][$key]['Quantity']){
                $y="selected";
                }
                echo "<option ";
                echo "value=\"$i\" ".$y.">", $i, "</option>\n";


            } ?>

       </select>
```

```
<script>
function get_price(val)
{
    var qty = $(val).val();
    var price = $("#price").html();
    var price =  qty * price;
    $("#price").html(price);
    return false;


}

</script>
```

Comment: THank you very much. but Is this javascript or jquery?

Comment: Just tel me what is javascript and jquery?

Comment: jquery is a framework that consists of built in functions.And in javascript we write our own functions.I don't know whether it is right. I am new to php

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment!!

Comment: @user2934937 Its jquery ... try this [Link](http://jeffgran.com/2009/06/03/javascript-jquery-vs-the-dom/)

Comment: I tried it out.But it is showing an error in this line  var price =(int)$("#price").html();

Comment: Can you please help me?\

Comment: remove (int) then try

Comment: I tried. But it is not working.Nothing happened in the page.THe page is just idle

Comment: When tried to alert var price = $("#price").html(); it didn't  worked.What will be the reason

Comment: YEAH i TRIED IT TOO.. but it is also not working.BUT val was alerted. and it worked

Comment: HI, I GOT IT. BUT I don't know how to set the result to the corresponding row. Please help me